# So many low-quality questions that are not homework per se

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I suggest we either expand the "homework sans effort" [close reason](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions) to cover more "low effort" and/or "completely clueless but opinionated" questions or create a new close reason to cover the latter kinds. On Psychology SE there is something like:

> This question is not framed in psychology or neuroscience. It is based on assumptions which are not made explicit, are not well-motivated (e.g., referenced), or are not held to be true within any of the research fields on-topic here.

To pick the most [recent example](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/25038/time-period-in-which-memory-loss-start-after-masturbation) closed like that over there:

> I want to exactly know that in how much time does the masturbation leads to memory loss and till what time? And what are the steps that should be taken to recover memory very very soon...? Please...help....please.

Basically, it's used when people are completely clueless about a topic but spout a theory anyway and somehow expect the experts to go along and answer their question in their pseudo-science framework. These are the scientific equivalent of a loaded question.

If I'm allowed a bit of pun on that, some questions here ask (not quite in such nakedly ludicrous terms, but indulge me)

> I've heard the Fed is printing stimulus money. When can I expect hyperinflation? I need to know so I spend all my savings before then. Please... help... please.

So, for here, I suggest something like

> This question is not framed in economics. It is based on assumptions which are not made explicit, are not well-motivated (e.g., referenced), or are not held to be true within economics.

Something like 90% of the recent questions on QE I've seen here (often using terms like "printing money" etc.) would qualify. I can't currently VTC them much because [there's no obvious close reason](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/serial-downvoting) for me to choose from the present list.

---

A more [recent howler](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/35943/does-federal-reserves-purchase-of-junk-bonds-create-unethical-incentives-and-mo):

> Does Federal Reserve's purchase of junk bonds create unethical incentives and moral hazard?

A long, ranty question soliciting (comments about) statements like

> This is the end of capitalism and free markets.

With an *accepted* answer that is a terse, reference-free quip:

> This is primarily to allow nationalisation of shale oil.

Welcome to Conspiracy Economics SE.

Comment: I like this suggestion, but note that you can always write your own close reason under off-topic/other. It is however not convenient to do so. Until your suggestion is implemented in some way I will simply come back to this meta question and copy your text.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic not because I think it should be closed, but because I want to demonstrate that one can give whatever reason they want to.

Comment: @Giskard: I appreciate the pun, but if I take your argument at face value, why even have more than one close reason available? Some would argue [that's a problem already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Paradox_of_Choice).

Comment: And yeah my proposal is obviously unnecessary. Amazing questions trigger amazing answers https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/35665/6210 "straight from out outsourced call center", I could say.

Comment: I do support your recommendation, I was merely offering an interim solution until its implementation. I understand that combined with the paradox of choice it also serves as a counterargument, but this is not the view I take.

Comment: I would support something like this as a closure reason. I am not sure that I have the ability to add this in.

Comment: I support this, sounds like what we need for regulating content on this site

Comment: To be honest, I prefer having many pre-written options despite being able to write my own reasons for closure. I am already moderating for free and time constrained. While minor, it's still additional work to formulate my own reason for closure. It may not cost excessive time, but (for me at least) it can be a mental hurdle.